# Using .row.add() after initialising datatable with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable, datatables

I've initialised a datatable with ajax and now when I try to add a row I get nothing.

Entering the add new row command into the console I get the following error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
>       at :2:10
>       at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:904:140)
>       at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:837:34)
>       at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:693:21)"

```
        // initialise table
        var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

            dom:    "<'row'<'col-sm-6' <'toolbar'> > >" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ route('admin.data') }}',
            columns: [
                {
                    "className":      'center',
                    "orderable":      false,
                    "data":           null,
                    "defaultContent": ''
                },
                { data: 'last_name' },
                { data: 'first_name' },
                { data: 'email' },
                { data: 'phone', orderable: false }
            ],
            order: [[1, 'asc']],
            initComplete: function() {
                $('td.center').html('<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>');
            }

        });

        // add new row
        $('#quick-access .btn-add').on('click', function() {
            var first = $('#val2').val();
            var last = $('#val1').val();
            var email = $('#val3').val();

            table.row.add( [
                'last_name': last,
                'first_name': first,
                'email': email,
                'phone': ''
            } ).draw();
            $("#quick-access").css("bottom","-115px");
        });
```

Currently once I trigger the row.add() function it updates the table but redraws it with no new row? Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the same structure with [`row.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29) as table structure.

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29):

> If a data structure is used (i.e. array or object) it must be in the same format as the other data in the table (i.e. if your table uses objects, pass in an object with the same properties here!).

For example:

```
 table.row.add( {
    'last_name': last,
    'first_name': first,
    'email': email,
    'phone': ''
 } ).draw();
```

You're also using server-side processing mode with `serverSide: true` and `draw()` causes the script to retrieve the data from the server again. Since your record is not on the server, DataTables retrieves records available on the server only and ignores your newly added record.

In this case your best bet would be to add the record on the server and then use `draw()` or `ajax.reload()` API methods.

Comment: Ok so I'll try adding it with an ajax request first then redraw it.I just thought this would be slower than redrawing it client side first then I was going to add it via ajax?

Comment: I guess this would be bad practice as you're giving the client confirmation before it's been successful.